# overwrite xmlns breaks xslt result

Tags: xml, xslt, notepad++, xslt-1.0

The issue is as follows, I have a simple XML file:

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Does not work
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And a XSL tranformation file

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="td">
        It works
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

If "td" is matched I expect to see "It works" as output as defined by the template.
If "td" is not matched, then I expect to see "Does not work" as the default templates will output all node values not handled by a custom template.
Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


        Does not work
```

However if I change the namespace declarations to xmlns:html="..." then the result changes.

xml:

```
<html:table xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <html:tr>
        <html:td>
            Does not work
        </html:td>
     </html:tr>
</html:table>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="html:td">
        It works
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


    It works
```

This is a simple example to isolate the issue, the xml for the real application is provided by third party software, overwriting xmlns declaration to xmlns: is not an option. My question is, how do I get this to work, result: "It works", without changing xmlns.

For the conversion I'm using notepad++ with XML tools plugin where there is a XSL tranformation option.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the first document (the one that has a *default* namespace):

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Does not work
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with the second XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="html:td">
        It works
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and you will be surprised by the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    It works
```

Declaring a namespace with a *prefix*:

```
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
```

is the usual way to deal with XML input documents that have a default namespace. If you have such a declaration in your stylesheet, `html:td` will mean exactly the same as the `td` element with a default namespace from the input document.

This is because *prefixes are actually irrelevant*. Prefixes like `html:`do not carry any meaning, it is the namespace URI that is meaningful. Prefixes are just a shorthand to avoid having to type (or read) the namespace URI for every single element. You should think of an element like

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
```

as

```
<{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}table>
```

and, analogously, think of

```
<html:table xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
```

as the same:

```
<{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}table>
```

---

Also, briefly commenting on:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
```

remember that an XSLT stylesheet is just a regular XML file and all the rules of XML apply to it. The only effect of declaring a default namespace in an XSLT stylesheet is: all elements that do not have a prefix (i.e. are in no other namespace) will be associated with this namespace.

But since all of the elements in your XSLT stylesheet have a prefix `xsl:`, the default namespace does not do anything. In a stylesheet like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>it works</result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

you can actually see what the default namespace does, because the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">it works</result>
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but I still don't understand why not prefixing it does not work. If there is no prefix, will it not default to the namespace declared by xmlns, since there is no conflict with another namespace I expected this to work.

Comment: @DemanB "*If there is no prefix, will it no default to the namespace declared by xmlns*" If there is no prefix, then it will select elements in no-namespace.

Comment: @DemanB Please let my try to explain this again: Your assumption is that in `xsl:template` elements, a default namespace declared in the `xsl:transform` element will apply to the value of the `select` attribute. But default namespaces only ever apply to XML elements, never to attributes and never to the values of attributes. There is functionality that does this, although I do not recommend it in this case: [`xpath-default-namespace`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xsltmistakes/#list4). Also, it requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Mathias Müller Thank you, your last comment explained it all, now the "XSLT stylesheet is just a regular XML file" comment is clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do I get this to work, result: "It works", without
>   changing xmlns.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="ns:td">
        It works
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, accepted the answer of Mathias Müller for the extra information. Thank You

Comment: "*accepted the answer of Mathias Müller for the extra information.*" And so you should!